# Ubuntu 16.04 Unknown interface

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, network-bridge

I have an issue when configuring a second nic for my ubuntu server. Look at this:

```
root@ubuntubox01:~# lshw -short | grep network
/0/100/15/0          ens160      network    VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
/0/100/16/0          ens192      network    VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
```

When I look at the IP Addresses:

```
root@ubuntubox01:~# ip addr sh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:b6:52:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/24 brd XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX scope global ens160
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb6:5289/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:50:56:b6:e2:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::250:56ff:feb6:e22d/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But if I do:

```
root@ubuntubox01:~# ifup ens192
Unknown interface ens192
```

Same thing happens when I try to use the interfaces file. Any ideas as to why ubuntu sees the physical interface but refuses to bring it up saying the interface is unknown?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 Server 64 bits. It is a virtual environment by the way.

Greetings,

C.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /etc/network/interfaces file,
it should contain:

```
auto ens192 
iface ens192 inet dhcp
```

or for static:

```
auto ens192 
iface ens192 inet static
#params
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
sudo dhclient eth0
```

replace `eth0` with the interface name. The snippet is taken from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConfigurationCommandLine/Automatic

Also, check the spelling of everything in /etc/network/interfaces. I had the same issue as you described, because the iface name was misspelled.